# Lampp/Apache - Make files not available from htdocs folder via HTTP

Tags: php, html, apache, lampp

i have lampp installed on my maschine with apache. I dont even know if that is relevant for my question...

i am trying to create a way (php, html) for users (from my website) to download files **which are not inside the htdocs folder** 
is that possible? the reason i want to know this is, that i don't want anyone else to have access to those files by just typing in the url of the file.

cheers, Friedrich

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php

Answer (score 0):

Several options, the least load is probably [`X-Sendfile`](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/)

Answer (score -1):

**yes, you can, as many as you want.**

Open the file [xamp_installation_folder]/apache/conf/httpd.conf in any text editor.Copy below lines after the htdocs  element after changing the directory to your own folder.

```
<Directory "C:/path/to/your/folder">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then search for this string: . Inside that element, add a new alias as followed:

```
Alias /yoursite/ "C:/path/to/your/folder/yoursite/"
Save the file and restart the XAMPP server.
```

[Complete link is here](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2011/11/making-xampp-to-serve-any-directory-outside-htdocs/)

Comment: _"the reason i want to know this is, that i don't want anyone else to have access to those files by just typing in the url of the file"_, which this doesn't solve.

Comment: I can think of putting password on htdocs folder using htaccess not to allow any access if you dont know the pass. Or edit php.ini and remove htdocs from default mapping. It should still server your other site.

Comment: You could do that, but then you'd either have to have one common password for everyone, or 2 locations to maintain user/pass combo's (for the .htaccess and for the PHP application, allthough technically it is possible to call on php in the authentication I wouldn't recommend it), and a side effect would be that if basic HTTP authentication isn't employed to log in to the site normally, logged in users have to reauthenticate, and those relying on saved passwords won't have them available in most UA's I know (html form and http authentication don't mix in their storage).

Comment: All in all: yes it would work, but far from user- and maintenance-friendly.

Comment: It would help if the question is clarifiy, is he serving from his local machine or using an Online web server

Comment: What difference would that make?

Comment: On local machine, you have full control. This is something I can visualize if hosting from my own PC. Even in that case, I'd like to know who the user are. On webserver, it is a different situation. All you get is a folder where you put stuff in, no htdocs folder.

Comment: That wholly depends. Hosting ranges from pure file-based non-scripted environments to renting a cluster of dedicated servers. Nowadays, a simple VPS isn't that much more expensive then some hosting packages. Even then, hosters differ greatly in things they are willing to install or alter for you. Some nothing, some almost everything. But I get the point that what is / can be available matters, it has been a while since I hosted on a server not under my total control :D.

Comment: i have a root server in the net.
if i put the files in a htacces protected folder (inside the document  root tree) can i provide it to the users via php (where they wouldnt need the htacces password)?

Comment: Is it a dedicated server? or you are just talking about WWW folder? Can you configure, which folder you want to serve you website from?